# Not able to add Custom phtml file on Product Page - Magento 2.3.6 CE

Tags: magento2.3

Not able to add/include my custom phtml file on product detailed page. Also I'm not able to remove any of the blocks.
If I remove or add any new phtml the alignment will become clumsy and reviews tab will disappear

Comment: please share code you tried

Comment: You need to share your code, that's is not big issue. There are many ways to add and remove section on product details page.

Comment: Unable to paste the entire code.

Comment: <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="mage/gallery/gallery.css"/>
    </head>
    <update handle="catalog_product_opengraph" />
    <update handle="page_calendar"/>
    <body>
 <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
        <attribute name="itemtype" value="http://schema.org/Product" />
        <attribute name="itemscope" value="itemscope"/>

Comment: I tried to remove reviews.tab